# cmp doesn't behave as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script

Perhaps I am missing something, but I have a bash script that takes the output of ls, makes a hash, and then takes another one. If the hashes match, no action. If they are different, it should email an admin and then overwrite the hash so they match once again. Here is the script:

```
logday="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
sdir="/home/admin/notify"
timestamp="$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')"
log="$sdir/log/$logday-notification.log"

if ! test -f $sdir/hash1; then
  touch $sdir/hash1
  ls -alR /mnt/DVR/3 | md5sum > $sdir/hash1
else
  echo "hash already present"
fi
ls -alR /mnt/DVR/3 | md5sum > $sdir/hash2
if cmp -s $sdir/hash1 $sdir/hash2; then
  echo "$timestamp - Hash matches, nothing to do." >> "$log"
else
  echo "$timestamp - Hash has changed! Sending notification. Writing new value to hash1" >> "$log"
  cp -f $sdir/hash1 $sdir/hash2
  echo "it changed" | mail -s "alert" email@gmail.com
fi
exit
```

So I run the script for the first time I get the log output of:

"Hash matches, nothing to do."

Makes sense. If I cat hash*, I get this

```
$ cat hash*
36d28cb4a6b384abe5c3acc81c93c891  -
36d28cb4a6b384abe5c3acc81c93c891  -
```

Again, makes sense

If I run it again, the hashes match, no email. Again, makes sense, nothing has changed yet.

Now, I make a change to the directory. I run the script. I get: " Hash has changed! Sending notification. Writing new value to hash1"

Yup makes sense, the hashes were different. The script overwrites the hashes so they should match now. Running cat hash* confirms this.

```
$ cat hash*
856d69a9b53008988d034c9504345541  -
856d69a9b53008988d034c9504345541  -
```

Both files are identical. But now, when I run the script again, it says they are still different!

I'm starting to run out of ideas why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. That was a quite well-formed first question.

Comment: Also: there's no point to the quotes in `logday="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
sdir="/home/admin/notify"
timestamp="$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')"
log="$sdir/log/$logday-notification.log"` What you should do is quote your variables when you use them, so `cp "$sdir"`, etc.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is with `cmp`?

Comment: Debug the `cmp` to eliminate it from the problem. Remove the `-s`, add `-v` (verbose), and report its status (it could be 2 for "trouble"). If a bug is not staring you in the face, it (or they) are equally likely to be anywhere, and you might as well cram in debug everywhere as you write the code.

Comment: It might be a good idea to first send the notification email and then copy the hash, in case something goes wrong and one operation completes but the other does not.

Comment: There's an additional, subtle source of discrepancy: in the timestamp field, `ls` by default shows the hours and minutes of times in the last 6 months, but instead the year of older ones. That will cause a change of output exactly 6 months after a file was last modified, even though the file's timestamp hasn't actually changed. (Depending on your platform, you may be able to work around that with `--full-time` and/or `--time-style`, but… (contd.)

Comment: …there may well be other issues too. I can't help thinking that just as it's [not good practice to parse `ls`'s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/298508), it's not good for other automated uses either.)

Comment: There's no need to `touch` the file before you redirect output to it.

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "$timestamp - Hash has changed! Sending notification. Writing new value to hash1" >> "$log"
cp -f $sdir/hash1 $sdir/hash2
```

You *say* you are writing a new value to `hash1`, but what you actually *do* is copy the old `hash1` value to `hash2`.

As a result, the two hashes will always be the same when the script is not running, but because the value is the old hash, the next run will trigger the notification again.

To fix, change the order of hashes in the `cp` command:

```
cp -f $sdir/hash2 $sdir/hash1
```

Comment: Change the `cp` to `mv`. It is a cheaper operation, and you will then spot the problem. You script tracing `echo`s will tell you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I probably shouldn't have put this together after work when my brain wasn't working. Works like a charm now.

Comment: @Joe a contributing factor is how the names of the hash files are meaningless and generic.  If you gave them names indicating their function, like `new_hash` and `previous_hash`, you would likely have noticed the `cp` command was backwards as you were writing it.  This idea is also applicable to the names of variables you use in your scripts - meaningful names are usually better than generic ones.